# Printing a (scientific) poster near Boğaziçi University in Istanbul

Tags: turkey, istanbul

I have to make a poster presentation at Boğaziçi University in two months and will not be able to bring the poster with me on the airplane. Therefore, I'd like to print it near the University from a PDF on A0 paper. Is there a copy shop or similar to do this? If so, how much to expect to pay?

Comment: +1 but there is some linen/canvas that you could print on that is foldable. Also airlines do allow poster rolls as additional carry on without qualms usually. Are you sure that is not an option?

Comment: Have you asked the conference organisers if they can arrange this? Some are happy to use the university's facilities for this, and it's worth checking.

Comment: yes - I already sent two emails to the organizers but did not receive any reply so far

Comment: @mts In the context of academic conferences, a poster has lots of text on it in a relatively small font (the sort of font you'd have to be about a metre away to read). You can find examples by Googling for something like "academic poster presentation". I highly doubt that it's possible to print on linen or canvas with sufficiently high resolution.

Comment: (+1) Might be worth asking on academia, must be a common problem.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm aware of conference posters at least in Science. It is possible (not exactly linen but your local copy shop will advice and I have seen it). @ Relaxed regarding posting on Academia yes, but aren't we discouraging cross-site posting?

Comment: @DavidRicherby you can print on fabric at 150 DPI if not more. Doubt that's not readable. However it might be too expensive for A0. My earlier comment gave the price in the wrong column. $115 for fabric at A0. Another option would be just get it delivered. From the UK you can find places that will deliver to Bulgaria for a few GBP

Comment: Related posts on Academia SE [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10206/travelling-for-an-academic-seminar-with-a-3648-inch-poster-board-on-a-flight) and [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/printing-a-poster-at-the-conference)

Comment: This post was flagged as off-topic for price-shopping. I disagree and have voted to leave open as it is mainly about the availability of such services, with pricing being a secondary question. The question is about the needs of an academic traveling to a conference and IMHO well within the scope of Travel SE.

Answer (score 2):

You can print in Besiktas. There are couple of print centers there and I don't think it would be more expensive than $10.

Here is coordinate of print centers. 
41.043398, 29.007704

Edit: [Google Maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/41%C2%B002'36.2%22N+29%C2%B000'27.7%22E/@41.0434902,29.0050528,16.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d41.043398!4d29.007704?hl=en)

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer and welcome to Travel SE. Looking forward to many contributions of yours here :) I edited your answer to include a link in Google Maps, you can rollback if you dislike. The place you suggest seems (by eye and not knowing the city) a bit far from the Boğaziçi University, do you know if there is anything even closer?

Comment: There must be a lot of places around Bogazici University but I don't know exactly. This place is 20 mins of bus drive from Bogazici University.